# ThreeJS - How to display an image sprite in its actual size?

Tags: javascript, button, three.js, size, sprite

I am attempting to create a clickable button for my 3D environment.
The buttion will be a .PNG image, loaded into ThreeJS as a sprite.

[Example button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD61t.png)

I have already succeeded in fixing the sprite to a position on the screen by attaching it to the camera itself, and making it appear on top of objects by using: "depthTest: false" when loading the sprite material.

Now, I wish to display the button in its native size, which is 50 x 50 pixels.
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it right using the Sprite.scale.set(); as results come out blurry.

How would I go about doing such a thing?

```js
var Loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var SMap_001 = Loader.load("button.png");
var SMat_001 = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  map: SMap_001,
  depthTest: false
});
var Sprite_001 = new THREE.Sprite(SMat_001);
Sprite_001.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 1);
camera.add(Sprite_001);
Sprite_001.position.set(0, -0.2, -2);
```

Above is an example of the code, when I'm loading up the sprite.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are determined to use a sprite, then see https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll look into both of your suggestions!